# Could you use the internet to store data in the transmission space between countries?

Tags: storage

Is it possible to bounce data back and forwards between lets say a USA computer and an Australian computer through the internet and just send these packets back and forwards and use this bounced data as a data storage?

As I understand it would take some time for the data to go from A to B, lets say 100 milliseconds, then therefore the data in transfer could be considered to be data in storage. If both nodes had a good bandwidth and free bandwidth, could data be stored in this transmission space? - by bounce the data back and forwards in a loop.

Would there be any reasons why this would not work.

---

The idea comes from a different idea I had some time ago where I thought you could store data in empty space by shooting laser pulse between two satellites a few light minutes apart. In the light minutes of space between then you could store data in this empty space as the transmission of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would there be any reasons why this would not work.

[Lost packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss). Although some protocols (like TCP) have means to prevent packet loss, it involves the sender re-sending lost packets as needed. That means each node must still keep a copy of  the data available to send it again (or the protocol might fail), so you'd still be using local storage while the communication does not complete.

Comment: There are approaches to deal with unreliable storage, simply storing the information redundantly.

Answer (score 1):

If you took any networking classes, you would know the End-to-End principle, which states

> The end-to-end principle states that application-specific functions ought to reside in the end hosts of a network rather than in intermediary nodes

Hence, you can not expect routers between your two hosts to keep the data for you. They have to freedom to discard it at anytime (or they themselves may crash at any time with your data in their buffer).

For more, you can read this wiki link:
[End-to-End principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle)

Answer (score 1):

It think this should actually work as in reality you store that information in various IO buffers of the numerous routers, switches and network cards. However the amount of storable information would probably be too small to have practical use, and network administrators of all levels are unlikely to enjoy and support such a creative approach.

Storing information in the delay line is a known approach and has been used to build memory devices in the past. However the past methods rely on delay during signal propagation over physical medium. As Internet mostly uses wires and electromagnetic waves that travel with the sound of light, not much information can be stored this way. Past memory devices mostly used sound waves.